# PHP parameters between 2 scripts

Tags: php

Script1:

```
<?php
/*
$file_url, $referer, $file_title are initialized in some way
*/
...
echo '<a href="download.php?url='.$file_url.'&referer='.$referer.'&name='.$file_title.'">Download</a>';

?>
```

Script2:

```
<?php

$file_url = $_GET['file_url'];
$referer = $_GET['referer'];
$file_name = $_GET['file_name']

?>
```

Since variables in script1 may be long strings. It makes problems when passing them through GET method. Which alternatives do I have in php for passing parameters between scripts?

Comment: Session vars, file storage, db storage.... the choice is endless

Comment: if I have N>50 such links

Comment: whats wrong for using POST method ,

Comment: @zan  you mean POST with forms or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a form, and set the method to post , and a hidden form field for the value you want to post.the link(href) either  become the link button or have an onclick action on the link that just submits the form.

hope this helps you

```
<form id="form_s" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="value">
  <input type="hidden" name="Of your choice " value="Some Value">
  <!-- more stuff you want to post -->
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="form_s.submit()">click to post values</a>
```